# Android BroadcastReceiver execution

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, execution

I work on an app and trying to figure out how exactly a `broadcastReceiver` in Android works. I understand that I can register for a specific event via an `Intent + BroadcastReceiver` and thereby my app is notified when this specific event happens.

However, what I am not sure how the `broadcastReceiver` is executed? Is the execution of my `program` stopped when the `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered and after the code in my `BroadcastReceiver` is executed it is jumping back to the line it stopped (kind of like an interrupt for `microcomputers`)? Or is it handled in a different way?

Comment: it is handled in the main UI thread - not in any background one

Comment: It's **queued** in main thread, unlike interrupt.